# Error in build while installing RTAI in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rtos

I am trying to install RTAI 5.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in Linux Kernel 4.1.18. I was following [this](https://sites.google.com/site/thefreakengineer/tutorials/rtai-5-0-1-lubuntu-16-04-x64-1) tutorial. But unfortunately I am stuck in this part

```
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-rtai
```

The error is:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'deb-pkg'. Stop.
```

What should be the target?

Comment: Maybe you are in the wrong directory. If you are, the target my be correct but the makefile is not found. Second point: You should replace the word "this" by a link to the tutorial you followed.